# How to add comparison lines to an lmplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I would like to combine the following lmplots I have. More specifically, the red lines are averages for each season, and I want to place them on their respective lmplots with the other data, instead of having them separate. Here is my code (note, the axes limits aren't working because the second lmplot is messing it up. It works when I just plot the initial data):

```
ax = sns.lmplot(data=data, x='air_yards', y='cpoe',col='season', lowess = True, scatter_kws={'alpha':.6, 'color': '#4F2E84'}, line_kws={'alpha':.6, 'color': '#4F2E84'})

ax = sns.lmplot(data=avg, x='air_yards', y= 'cpoe',lowess=True, scatter=False, line_kws={'linestyle':'--', 'color': 'red'}, col = 'season')

axes.set_xlim([-5,30])
axes.set_ylim([-25,25])

ax.set(xlabel='air yards')
```

And here is the output. Simply put, I want to take those red lines and put them on their respective year plots above. Thanks!
[image: And here is the output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible the way you want, so maybe something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#dummy example
data = pd.DataFrame({'air_yards': range(1,11), 
                     'cpoe': range(1,11), 
                     'season': [1,2,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2]})
avg = pd.DataFrame({'air_yards': [1, 10]*3, 
                    'cpoe': [2,2,5,5,8,8], 
                    'season': [1,1,2,2,3,3]})

# need this info
n = data["season"].nunique()

# create the number of subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=n, sharex=True, sharey=True)

# now you need to loop through unique season
for ax, (season, dfg) in zip(axes.flat, data.groupby("season")):
    # set title
    ax.set_title(f'season={season}')

    # create the replot for data
    sns.regplot("air_yards", "cpoe", data=dfg, ax=ax, 
                lowess = True, scatter_kws={'alpha':.6, 'color': '#4F2E84'}, 
                line_kws={'alpha':.6, 'color': '#4F2E84'})

    # create regplot for avg
    sns.regplot("air_yards", "cpoe", data=avg[avg['season'].eq(season)], ax=ax, 
                lowess=True, scatter=False, 
                line_kws={'linestyle':'--', 'color': 'red'})

plt.show()
```

you get 
[image]

Comment: I ran the code once and it worked, ran it a second time and I got an error: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'flat'

Comment: @bismo this error happens when the number of `ncols` in `plt.subplots` is equal to 1, can you check if it is the case in your second try?

Comment: I got it figured out and plotted! However, the subplots are shaped rectangular like in your response, and I don't want them to be. I would like them to be more square. How could I go about doing this? Also, I was trying to add a new title for the whole subplot, above the season numbers. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like plt.suptitle() did the trick! Now, just to figure out the subplot shapres...

Comment: Looks like I also just needed to change the figure size to get a better shape. My plot looks great now, thank you!

Comment: @bismo sorry late answer I was sleeping ^^ glad you figure out how to get your desired output. it is true that the rectangular shapes were a bit ugly..